# Fonction returning null while doing query in Mysql database using Android Studio Java

Tags: android, mysql

I'm building a mobile app that search for doctors and show result as markers on map using MySQL database and Android Studio, this function is supposed to connect to mySQL by a php url and select some informations from the database table that are linked to what the user types in the editText. The problem is that the function returns Null everytime for that i tried printf to check for the JSON result before i translate it to markers (by the way i checked the connection to the database using an insert function it worked perfectly so my project is connected to the external database ) but i don't know why this function is returning Null. Hope you give me some help i'm a beginner :)

```
ArrayList<String> email;
    ArrayList<String> horaire;
    ArrayList<String> jours;
    ArrayList<String> lang;
    ArrayList<String> lat;
    ArrayList<String> nome;
    ArrayList<String> specialite;
    ArrayList<String> telephone;
    ArrayList<String> type;
    ArrayList<String> adress;

     String MySQLExecuteQuery(String url, String query) {
        map.clear();
        specialite = new ArrayList();
        telephone = new ArrayList();
        horaire = new ArrayList();
        email = new ArrayList();
        adress = new ArrayList();
        jours = new ArrayList();
        type = new ArrayList();
        nome = new ArrayList();
        lang = new ArrayList();
        lat = new ArrayList();
        String spec= Specialite.getText().toString();
        String toReturn = "Null";
        Response[] response = new Response[1];
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("msg", "SELECT longitude,latitude, mobile, horaire,email,adresse,jours, type"+
                        " FROM PRIVE"+
                        "WHERE specialite LIKE '%"+spec+"%'"+
                        "OR nom LIKE '%"+ spec +"%'"+
                        "OR adresse LIKE '%"+ spec +"%'")
                .build();
         Request request = new Request.Builder()
                 .url(url + query)
                 .post(formBody)
                 .build();

        try {
            response[0] = client.newCall(request).execute();

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response[0].body().string());

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject student = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String longitude =student.getString("longitude");
                String latitude =student.getString("latitude");
                specialite.add(student.getString("specialite"));
                telephone.add(student.getString("mobile"));
                horaire.add(student.getString("horaire"));
                email.add(student.getString("email"));
                adress.add(student.getString("adresse"));
                jours.add(student.getString("jours"));
                type.add(student.getString("type"));
                nome.add(student.getString("nom"));
                lat.add(student.getString("latitude"));
                lang.add(student.getString("longitude"));
                System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());

                LatLng mihoubi = new LatLng((Double.parseDouble(longitude)),Double.parseDouble(latitude));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mihoubi).title(""+i).snippet(""+nome+","+specialite+""));
                map.getMinZoomLevel();

                System.out.println("Object" + i + ":"+student);
                toReturn= jsonArray.toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toReturn;
     }
```